# how to parallel this for loop?

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to learn openmp and trying run the second loop in parallel by adding "#pragma omp parallel for",but it is not working any suggestions?

```
  if (hi - lo > 3) {
      for ( i = hi-4; i >= lo; i-- ) {
         tmp = fmap[i];
         ec_tmp = eclass[tmp];
         #pragma omp parallel for
         for ( j = i+4; j <= hi && ec_tmp > eclass[fmap[j]]; j += 4 )
            fmap[j-4] = fmap[j];
         fmap[j-4] = tmp;
      }
   }
```

Comment: this from a project to a company that i need to make some specific loops parallel ,so they asked me for the second one not the first , but let's say i want to make the first parallel i just need to add "#pragma omp parallel for" and that's it ?

Comment: ok thank you that was helpfull.

Comment: 1) Your code looks potentially racy to me. There seems to be a read-after-write race in the j loop. (Consider two threads, with i==0, and hi==8. One thread reads fmap[4] and writes fmap[0], the other reads fmap[8] and writes fmap[4]. Suppose the second runs first; then fmap[0] will end up containing the original fmap[8], a result that's not possible in the serial run). 2) that code shouldn't compile, since the loop condition on the parallel loop is not valid! So, I don't think you have OpenMP enabled!

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. to your knowledge is there any possible way to parallel this loop    for (p = split; *p != 0; p++) if (*p == ' ') *p = '0';